# How to add a PNG logo to Tailwind CSS navbar using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

This is the code and I want to add a PNG logo in place of the SVG logo, but every time I add an `img` element, nothing gets rendered.
The image/logo I want to add has to be more or less the same size as the SVG logo.

[image]

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    
    export const Navbar = () => {
      const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    
      const handleClick = () => {
        setActive(!active);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <nav className='flex items-center flex-wrap bg-green-400 p-3 '>
            <Link href='/'>
              <a className='inline-flex items-center p-2 mr-4 '>
                <svg
                  viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                  className='fill-current text-white h-8 w-8 mr-2'
                >
                  <path d='M12.001 4.8c-3.2 0-5.2 1.6-6 4.8 1.2-1.6 2.6-2.2 4.2-1.8.913.228 1.565.89 2.288 1.624C13.666 10.618 15.027 12 18.001 12c3.2 0 5.2-1.6 6-4.8-1.2 1.6-2.6 2.2-4.2 1.8-.913-.228-1.565-.89-2.288-1.624C16.337 6.182 14.976 4.8 12.001 4.8zm-6 7.2c-3.2 0-5.2 1.6-6 4.8 1.2-1.6 2.6-2.2 4.2-1.8.913.228 1.565.89 2.288 1.624 1.177 1.194 2.538 2.576 5.512 2.576 3.2 0 5.2-1.6 6-4.8-1.2 1.6-2.6 2.2-4.2 1.8-.913-.228-1.565-.89-2.288-1.624C10.337 13.382 8.976 12 6.001 12z' />
                </svg>
                <span className='text-xl text-white font-bold uppercase tracking-wide'>
                  Talwind CSS
                </span>
              </a>
            </Link>
            <button
              className=' inline-flex p-3 hover:bg-green-600 rounded lg:hidden text-white ml-auto hover:text-white outline-none'
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              <svg
                className='w-6 h-6'
                fill='none'
                stroke='currentColor'
                viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap='round'
                  strokeLinejoin='round'
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d='M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16'
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
            {/*Note that in this div we will use a ternary operator to decide whether or not to display the content of the div  */}
            <div
              className={`${
                active ? '' : 'hidden'
              }   w-full lg:inline-flex lg:flex-grow lg:w-auto`}
            >
              <div className='lg:inline-flex lg:flex-row lg:ml-auto lg:w-auto w-full lg:items-center items-start  flex flex-col lg:h-auto'>
                <Link href='/'>
                  <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white '>
                    Home
                  </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href='/'>
                  <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white'>
                    Services
                  </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href='/'>
                  <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white'>
                    About us
                  </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href='/'>
                  <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white'>
                    Contact us
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Also if possible please link a good similar example.

Comment: Can you post your example `img` tag where you are replacing your `svg`?

Answer (score 0):

Use next/image, these are some examples.

```
Layout = fill
code - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/layout-fill.js
preview - https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/layout-fill

Layout = fixed
code - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/layout-fixed.js
preview - https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/layout-fixed

Layout = responsive
code - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/layout-responsive.js
preview - https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/layout-responsive
```